# yaml bad indentation of a mapping entry gitlab?

Tags: yaml

I am trying to implement a ci/cd pipeline using gitlab and i created a ci file with the following content.

```
stages:
    - deploy
image:
   name: "ubuntu:16.04"

first-pipeline:test:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - executor:docker
  only:
    refs:
      - branches
      - schedules
  script:
    - export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False
    - echo "Job:  $job_param"
    - ansible-playbook -i production.ini -e "job_id=$job_param ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu" my-playbook.yml -l "10.37.23.230"
    - apk add curl
    - curl -X POST http://98.121.222.32:8080/api/v2/removejob -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{"jobId": $job_param}"
    - echo $query
    - echo "Executed at= $now"
```

I keep running into the following error message : `bad indentation of a mapping entry`

```
 24 |  ... 
 25 |  ... ubuntu" my-playbook.yml -l "10.37.23.230"
 26 |  ... 
 27 |  ... application/json' -d "{"jobId": $job_param}"
-----------------------------------------^
 28 |  ... 
 29 |  ...
```

Any suggestion on how to fix it? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try `application/json' -d "{'jobId': $job_param}"`

Comment: @RenaudC5 That did not work sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked :-

```
'curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://98.121.222.32:8080/api/v2/removejob -d "{"jobId": $job_param}"'
```